# How to make sure all combinations for each number are given in an integer composition recursion in Python?

Tags: python, recursion, math, integer

I'm watching the MIT OCW 2008 Introduction to Computer Science and Programming, and trying to do the assignments. This is informal so there's no grading involved. There's this problem where you have to have to buy specific numbers of nuggets with packs containing 6, 9, and 20 nuggets. The aim is to learn to how to use recursions in Python. I'm solving for up to 65 nuggets.

I've written the code below. It kind of works, but the problem is, I get exactly one solution for each number I input. How do I make sure that I get all the possible combinations for each number of total nuggets?

```
def testtheorem(x):
    for a in range(0,15):
        for b in range(0,15):
            for c in range(0,15):
                y = 6*a + 9*b + 20*c
                if y == x and x < 66:
                    print ("For", int(x), "total;")
                    print ("6 piece can be", int(a))
                    print ("9 piece can be", int(b))
                    print ("20 piece can be", int(c))
                    testtheorem(x+1)
                    return
```

Comment: There are two questions possible here: 1) represent some N as `6x+9x+20z` or 2) provide such representations for all numbers from 1 to N. These questions require different solutions, which one are you asking?

Comment: @gog Hi, I'm trying to find all possible pack combinations for each number from the first input to the upper limit (65). It's similar to the latter option, but from the input number to 65 instead of 1 to input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a quick go at this question, following the comment from gog.

The reason that you are only getting one answer for each answer you input is that you are returning prematurely.

Each time you find the first answer, you create a new child function and look for an answer in this number.
Eventually, you reach 66 which can never have an answer. Then you start heading back, all the way to the top - to your input number.

I drew a small example with starting at 64:

[image]

To solve your problem, you need to change at which point in the function you are calling the recursive function and when you are returning.

Other than that, your code is on the right track.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was my problem. After changing the indentation, the code worked.

Answer (score 1):

Let's change `testtheorem` behaviour. Note that recursion usage for composition of the next sum is not relevant here - there are more simple and clear approaches.

At every step we know maximum possible number of current items to fit in the needed sum, so make real limit for loop counter rather than arbitrary value 15. At the final stage we don't need loop - just calculate number of items for the rest of sum.

When sum is reached, print variant and continue to explore another variants. Also I added "no solutions"message (your values 6,9 are not mutually prime, so many small sums are impossible)

Now we able to get solutions for any `x` sum

```
def testtheorem(x):
    noSol = True
    print ("For", int(x), "total:")
    for a in range(x//6+1):
        for b in range((x-a*6)//9+1):
            c  = (x-a*6-b*9)//20
            y = 6*a + 9*b + 20*c
            if y == x:
                print (f"6 * {a} + 9 * {b} + 20 * {c}")
                noSol = False
    if noSol:
        print("   no solutions")

for x in range(1, 100):
    testtheorem(x)
```

example:

```
For 43 total:
   no solutions
For 44 total:
6 * 1 + 9 * 2 + 20 * 1
6 * 4 + 9 * 0 + 20 * 1
```

But we can use recursion to add the possibility to use any number of items and any item values, not only predefined and hard-coded ones (but recursion isn't the only way for this!). We provide item list in `packets` argument.

For simpilicity I collect current solution in the string for the next recursion level

```
def testRec(x, packets, idx = 0, s = ""):
    if idx == 0:
        print(f"For {x} total:")
    if idx == len(packets):
        if x == 0:
            print(s)
    else:
        for i in range(x//packets[idx]+1):
            testRec(x - packets[idx]*i, packets, idx + 1, 
                    s + f"{packets[idx]}*{i} " + ("+ " if idx < len(packets)-1 else ""))

for x in range(1, 20):
    testRec(x, [2,5,8,13])
```

Example:

```
For 15 total:
2*0 + 5*3 + 8*0 + 13*0 
2*1 + 5*0 + 8*0 + 13*1 
2*1 + 5*1 + 8*1 + 13*0 
2*5 + 5*1 + 8*0 + 13*0
```